# parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2 (bash)

Tags: json, bash, syntax-error, jq

I'm working with json in bash, but I'm getting this parse error:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 2
```

What's wrong with this block of code?

```
jsonStr=$(cat << EOF
'{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}'
EOF
)
jsonStr=$(jq 'del(.key3)' <<<"$jsonStr")
STRING="hello"
jsonStr=$(jq '. + {'"$STRING"': "value4"}' <<<"$jsonStr")
echo $jsonStr
```

Comment: In addition to the literal quotes making your data no longer JSON (which is the main issue, and covered in markp-fuso's answer), note that `echo $jsonStr` is inherently buggy. See [BashPitfalls #14](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) and [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) -- as in markp's answers, you need double quotes around your parameter expansions, even if their results are passed to `echo`, to prevent potential surprises

Comment: The correct input still contains no numeric literal.  The error message is misleading —and doesn't say it comes from jq...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `$(cat << EOF ...)` construct is passing the single quotes along as part of the data, ie:

```
$ jsonStr=$(cat << EOF
'{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}' 
EOF
)
$ echo "${jsonStr}"
'{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}'
```

Notice the leading/trailing single quotes.

To get past the parsing error you want to get rid of the single quotes, eg:

```
$ jsonStr=$(cat << EOF
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}
EOF
)

# or

$ jsonStr='{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}'
```

Both of the above give us:

```
$ echo "${jsonStr}"
{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}
```

And now the `jq/del` works as expected:

```
$ jq 'del(.key3)' <<< "${jsonStr}"
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

And then the `+` operation also works:

```
$ STRING="hello"
$ jq 'del(.key3)' <<< "${jsonStr}"  | jq '. + {'"$STRING"': "value4"}'
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "hello": "value4"
}
```

---

Pulling this all together:

```
jsonStr='{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}'
jsonStr=$(jq 'del(.key3)' <<< "${jsonStr}")
STRING="hello"
jsonStr=$(jq '. + {'"${STRING}"': "value4"}' <<< "${jsonStr}")
echo "${jsonStr}"
```

Which generates:

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "hello": "value4"
}
```